# knockout hide all not active elements

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Hi I have a problem to create correct function to show/hide elements. Goal is simple when you click on list element you will see div (template) with more info. Now you must click again in this same list element to hide this element. What I want to do: 
example, when I click on first element on a list and template for this element will be showed, I go to second element on a list (or last or any else) I click on it and I want to hide all open elements (templates) but I want to see only active element for a element what I clicked. Now I can open many elements in this same time, and I want to change it for a open only active element and hide all rest. This is possible to do in knonckout? Or maybe I must use jquery for that? Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0xgLmm3/)

HTML

```
<form action="#"> 
    <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off"> 
  </form>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <ul class="name-list" data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
          <li data-bind="attr:{class: $index == 0 ? 'active' : ''}, click: toggleshowMoreInfo" role="button">
            <span class="full-name" data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
          </li>

          <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" data-bind="slideVisible: showMoreInfo, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8 hidden-xs" data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
        <div class="row" data-bind="slideVisible: showMoreInfo, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- template for presonal information -->
  <script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <p><span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></p>
    </div>
  </script>
```

JS

```
var data = [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Barlow",
      "last": "Moore"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Valeria",
      "last": "Meadows"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Constance",
      "last": "Singleton"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Wilder",
      "last": "Steele"
    }]
  }
];

  var stringStartsWith = function (startsWith, string) {          
    string = string || "";
    if (startsWith.length > string.length)
        return false;
    return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
  };

  ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
      var duration = allBindings.get('fadeDuration') || 400;
      if (valueUnwrapped == true)
        setTimeout(function(){ $(element).fadeIn(duration); }, duration);
      else
        $(element).fadeOut(duration);
    }
  };

  /* show all data from json */
  function PersonInfo(data) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.name[0].first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(data.name[0].last);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);

    this.showMoreInfo = ko.observable(false);
    this.toggleshowMoreInfo = function () {
      this.showMoreInfo(!this.showMoreInfo())
    }
  }

  function PersonInfoViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.query = ko.observable('');
    self.mappedPersonalData = $.map(data, function(item) {  
      return new PersonInfo(item) 
    });
    self.filteredPeople = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.mappedPersonalData.filter(function (value) {
            if(self.query() === '' || self.query() === null){
               return true; //no query
            }
            if (stringStartsWith(self.query().toLowerCase(), value.firstName().toLowerCase()) || stringStartsWith(self.query().toLowerCase(), value.lastName().toLowerCase())){
               return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }); 
  }

  var viewModel = new PersonInfoViewModel();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible with knockout. All you need to do is move your toggle function up to the PersonInfoViewModel, and inside that loop through the other personInfo models to close them.

```
self.toggleshowMoreInfo = function (person) {
    var people = self.filteredPeople();
    for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++){
        if(people[i] !== person && people[i].showMoreInfo()){
            people[i].showMoreInfo(false);
        }
    }
    person.showMoreInfo(!person.showMoreInfo());      
}
```

Then change your click binding to `$parent.toggleshowMoreInfo`

Revised [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/9swam66o)

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this greatly by making your click handler set a `selectedPerson` property, and add a binding to your template divs to compare the current `person` object to the `selectedPerson` object. That way, you won't have to do any looping at all. Knockout will do it all for you. E.g.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
    <li data-bind="click: toggleSelectedPerson">
        <span class="full-name" data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
    </li>
    <div data-bind="slideVisible: $parent.selectedPerson() === $data, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
</ul>

<div data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
    <div data-bind="slideVisible: $parent.selectedPerson() === $data, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
</div>

// your model config
this.selectedPerson = ko.observable(null);
this.toggleSelectedPerson = function (person) {
  this.selectedPerson(this.selectedPerson() === person ? null : person);
}
// your model config continued...
```

Nabbed and updated JSFiddle from the another answer: https://jsfiddle.net/9swam66o/3/